# amdgpu segfault amdgpu_dri.so

Tags: drivers, vlc, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I'm in latest 18.04.1, amd64, AMD rx550GPU. kernel 4.18.0-041800-generic

I have the amdgpu-pro 18.30 drivers installed.
I have restricted codecs etc all installed.

Anytime I try to play a h264 or h265 video in videos or vlc, I get this error:

```
vlc[6896]: segfault at 38 ip 00007fadd6781224 sp 00007fadac1bf650 error 4 in amdgpu_dri.so[7fadd5748000+2213000]
Sep 11 21:17:06 2990wx kernel: [  523.588331] Code: 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 10 8b 40 4c c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 89 f7 eb eb 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 0$
Sep 11 21:26:37 2990wx kernel: [ 1094.334784] vlc[15739]: segfault at 38 ip 00007fa072781224 sp 00007fa050150650 error 4 in amdgpu_dri.so[7fa071748000+2213000]
Sep 11 21:26:37 2990wx kernel: [ 1094.334790] Code: 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 10 8b 40 4c c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 89 f7 eb eb 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 0$
Sep 11 21:28:34 2990wx kernel: [ 1211.787800] vlc[16530]: segfault at 38 ip 00007efe42781224 sp 00007efe281e0650 error 4 in amdgpu_dri.so[7efe41748000+2213000]
Sep 11 21:28:34 2990wx kernel: [ 1211.787805] Code: 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 10 8b 40 4c c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 89 f7 eb eb 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 0$
Sep 11 21:37:48 2990wx kernel: [ 1766.201357] rfkill: input handler enabled
```

It looks like the drivers are loaded fine etc. Hardware seems fine.

Any ideas?
Chrome can play youtube videos fine. So I'm assuming it's a GL thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue here.

Ubuntu 18.04
  AMDGPU-PRO 18.30
  VEGA 56.

AMD GPU can play H.265 with 4K 60fps by using VAAPI hardware decoding,
but PRO can not do that. The explanation is all AMD decoding is not saved at libs maybe it's saving it in /mnt.  Hence the most players can not find the .so. https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=335740&pid=2776855#

I really want to use the PRO driver because the performance is real good and supports Vulkan  (2K 100fps on DOTA2). Now the circumstance is if you want to play 4K video, you must use the non-PRO driver, otherwise you need to use PRO driver when you want to play games.

If you have any solution in the future, please let me know.